# Inertia tensor in two dimensions

Tags: tensor-calculus, moment-of-inertia

Let $\mathbf x$ be some vector in a two-dimensional euclidean vector space, then there exists a unique tensor such that
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}x_2x_2&-x_1x_2\\-x_2x_1&x_1x_1\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
is the representation w.r.t. each orthonormal basis.$^1$ Someone suggested that it looks like the inertia tensor for a single particle with $m=1$. Is this correct? Could someone please elaborate on this, as [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia)  only discusses the 3-dim. case?

---

$^1$ This is e.g. proven on page 937 of Riley, Hobson and Bence, 3rd edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct.  The tensor given can be written in coordinate-free form as
$$
T_{ij} = \delta_{ij} |\vec{x}|^2 - x_i x_j
$$
which can be seen to be equivalent to [the expression given in Wikipedia for the inertia tensor,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_of_inertia#Inertia_tensor) for a body containing a single particle with $m = 1$.

That said, it should be noted that the mathematical properties of rotations in 2-D are quite different from those in 3-D, and one cannot easily interpret the above tensor as having anything to do with rotational dynamics in 2-D.  In particular, angular velocity and angular momentum are effectively (signed) scalar quantities in 2-D, and so the moment of inertia is just a scalar quantity as well.